# Create recurring billing profile in paypal based on previous purchase

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

In Beanstream, it is possible to create a recurring profile account off a previous purchase as mentioned in their site:

> If a client has already made a purchase or had a pre-authorization performed on their credit card, a recurring billing account can be created from an existing Beanstream transaction record. This will prevent you from having to collect billing and card information more than once.

Is this also possible with Paypal? If yes, how?

EDIT:

I'm not asking if it's possible through the API. I'm asking if it's possible through the Paypal backend/account pages.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways you could do this, and it depends on the transaction that you ran before, and specifically what type of PayPal service you are using such as Payflow or PayPal.  If this was for an Express Checkout Transaction, you would not be able to set up a profile for this as there would of needed to be a couple of additional profiles passed over in the initial SetExpressCheckout API call to allow you to come back and create a recurring payment.  If you are using Payflow, you can use an existing transaction to create a profile.  If you are using PayPal, there would not be a way to use an existing transaction to create a profile.  However, you could use the existing transaction to create a recurring profile through your system rather than PayPal's system.  You would just perform a reference transaction API call every time you needed to charge the buyer again.  You could set your system up to run a cron job every day, and check to see who needs to be billed.

Converting an Existing Transaction Into a Profile (Payflow Example)

The following example Payflow parameter string creates a profile for an original transaction that had a PNREF value of xyz123 and specifies a payment amount of $42. You must set the ORIGID value to the original transaction’s PNREF value.

"TRXTYPE=R&TENDER=C&PARTNER=PayPal&VENDOR=Acme&USER=Acme&PWD=a1b2c3d4&ACTION=A&PROFILENAME=RegularSubscription&ORIGID=XYZ123&START=12012002&PAYPERIOD=WEEK&TERM=12&OPTIONALTRX=S&OPTIONALTRXAMT=2.00&COMMENT1=First-timecustomer&AMT=42.00"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I was asking if I can make a recurring profile via paypal's backend or account pages, not via an api call. In Beanstream, I can login to my merchant account. Go to the list of transactions and select a transaction and make a recurring profile based on that transaction (that is, using the credit card and billing info in that transaction). Is this possible with Paypal? I'm guessing,  based on your answer, that there's no way?